# Writing data in different files in C

Tags: c, file, loops

I'm studying C at the moment and I'm not that good yet. I am trying to write a program where I want to enter some people's name and create at the same time a .txt file with their name. For example if I type "Richard" it will create the file Richard.txt. And inside the .txt file I want to write again their name.

The only problem is that after I type the first name and create the first .txt file, entering a new name will not create a new .txt file. But instead it will put the second name in the first .txt file after the first name.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <conio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct personnel
{
 char name[40]; 
};

int addPatient(struct personnel patient[], int noAgt);
void writeFile(struct personnel patient[], int noAgt, char filename[]);
void emptyBuffer(void);

int main()
{
    struct personnel patient[50];
    int ch = 'X';
    int noAgt = 0; 
    char filename[100];
    while (ch != 'q')
    {
    printf("\na)\tEnter new patient"
    "\nb)\tWrite file"
    "\nc)\tExit program"
    "\n\nSelect: ");
    ch = getche(); 
    printf("\n\n");
    switch (ch)
        {
        case 'a' :
        noAgt = addPatient(patient, noAgt);
        break;
        case 'b' :
        writeFile(patient, noAgt, filename);
        break;
        case 'c' :
        exit(0);
        }
    }
}

int addPatient(struct personnel patient[], int noAgt)
{
 printf("\nPatient %d.\nEnter name: ", noAgt + 1); 
 scanf("%39[^\n]", patient[noAgt].name);
 while(getchar() != '\n') 
 {
    ;
 }
 return ++noAgt;
}

void writeFile(struct personnel patient[], int noAgt, char filename[])
{
    int i;
    FILE *fptr;
    struct personnel rec;
    strcpy(filename, patient[i].name);
    emptyBuffer();
    strcat(filename, ".aow.txt");
    fptr = fopen(filename, "w");
    for(i = 0; i < noAgt; i++)
    {
        rec = patient[i];
        fprintf(fptr, "Name: %s ",  rec.name);
    }
    fclose(fptr);
    printf("\nFile of %d patients written.\n", noAgt);
}

void emptyBuffer(void) /* Empty keyboard buffer */
{
 while(getchar() != '\n')
 {
     ;
 }
}
```

"int addPatient(struct personnel patient[], int noAgt)" Is the bit where I enter the name of the person that goes in writeFile().

"void writeFile(struct personnel patient[], int noAgt, char filename[])" Is the bit where I write the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first advice is: If you don't need the **filename** variable in main, then move it to writeFile(). Less parameters moving around and makes your code cleaner.

Your issue is inside the writeFile() function:

```
strcpy(filename, patient[i].name);
```

You never initialized your **i** variable. It's likely always getting initialized to 0 thus you're always writing to the first file you created. Try changing that line to this:

```
strcpy(filename, patient[noAgt-1].name);
```

And you should see the code working better. Still not the best solution in my opinion, since **noAgt** should probably not increment before writing the file. But it should get you going on cleaning up your code.